# 8 gb of RAM in a new macbook?

Tags: memory, macbook

I know that apple doesn't sell macbooks (just the vanilla, white macbook, not the pro models) with 8 gb of RAM but I'm wondering if it's possible to upgrade one to 8 gb of RAM. Anyone done it?

Comment: Consider editing this post to explicitly name the generation / date of general availability of the model you're referring to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MacBook support two RAM slots, each of which can be 4GB. So yes, you can upgrade to 8GB.

Comment: Right, that's true in theory. I'm wondering if anyone has actually done it and has confirmed that the machine will utilize all 8 gb.

Comment: @swingley: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Chipset, hardware/manufacturer limitations. Even simple mainboard manufacturers limit it. Do you still have to ask when it comes to Apple? :P

Comment: @swingley @Shiki Apple's published RAM specs are what they actually tested with and will provide technical support for. They err on the side of caution on this.